# *ngFor fails to populate any values regardless of formatting

Tags: angular, typescript

HTML:

```
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="name" [(ngModel)]="order.name">
        </div>   
        <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let item of items">
                <input  
                type="checkbox" 
                (change)="onChange(item, $event.target.checked)" class="form-control"/>
                <label class="tooltip">{{item.name}}
                    <span class="tooltiptext">{{item.desc}}</span>
                </label>
                <label>{{item.price}}</label>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ddown">Select Table:</label>
        <select  name="ddown" formControlName="tableSelected" class="form-control">
            <option disabled>Select Table</option>
            <option *ngFor="let table of tables" value="table">Table{{table}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <mat-dialog-actions>
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!itemchecked && !form.valid">Order Now</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
</form>
</div>
```

(Relevant) Typescript:

```
export class PlaceOrderComponent implements OnInit {

  orders : Order[]; 
  tables : number[] = [1, 5, 7];
  order : Order;
  items: Item[] = [new Item("Drink", 5, "A vintage wine of your choice"), 
  new Item("Steak", 20, "Filet Mignon garnished with parsley"), 
  new Item("Salad", 5, "Prepared according to your specification"), 
  new Item("Roll", 3, "Served with butter"), 
  new Item("Soup", 3, "Daily special")];
  itemchecked : Boolean = false;
  form = new FormGroup({
    tableSelected: new FormControl(['', Validators.required]),
    name: new FormControl(['', Validators.required])
  });
  constructor(
  private os: OrderService,
  public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PlaceOrderComponent>) {

   }
```

The result of the above code is that neither the checkboxes nor the dropdown options are rendered despite being hardcoded (although the dropdown itself and first option do render). I've attempted to format the HTML in various different ways (trying different tags, moving the directive around, even converting the component into a non-dialog context) with zero success. What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Do you get a console error?

Comment: Please replicate your scenario in a stackblitz instance and share the link with us. It would help us help you :)